# Why does the holy Q'uran begin with "In the name of Allah , the Compassionate, the Merciful."?

Tags: quran

One of the founders of Hindu nationalism, Swami Dayanand Srswati, wrote a criticism of the Quran.

- [An Examination Of The Doctrine Of Islam](https://www.aryasamajjamnagar.org/chapterfourteen.htm)

Here his first question was regarding *Bismillahir Rahmanir Rahim* which made me curious.

- "(I begin this book) In the name of Allah , the Compassionate, the Merciful." (1*:1.)

> According to Islam, Q’uran is the Word of Allah , but it appears from
> the above passage that the author of Q’uran was some person other than
> Allah, since had it been Allah himself, he would not have said: "(I
> begin this book) in the name of Allah etc." He would have instead
> said: "I am writing this book for the instruction of mankind." If it
> be said that by beginning His book in this fashion, he means to teach
> men as to what they should say when about to do a thing, it cannot be
> true, since some men will do even sinful deeds in the name of Allah
> and thereby bring disgrace on Him.

Why does the holy Q'uran begin with "In the name of Allah, the Compassionate, the Merciful." rather than "I am writing this book for the instruction of mankind."?

Comment: Who are you to say what Allah would and would not do? Illeism is a common tool in language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How would Allah begin a Book?**

The objection is that had Allah authored the Quran He would have begun it as follows:

> He would have instead said: "I am writing this book for the instruction of mankind."

This objection is nothing but a personal opinion.

One can easily counter this opinion by saying that it is actually more appropriate that the author first names himself. Starting with "I am writing this" would leave the reader in confusion as to who is talking and why he should listen to the author. Hence the Quran begins with the name and introduction of the author:

> In the name of Allah, the Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful.
>
> [All] praise is [due] to Allah, Lord of the worlds -
>
> The Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful,
>
> Sovereign of the Day of Recompense.

And after the introduction of the author the reader is taught a supplication for guidance so that he can receive benefit from the Book:

> It is You we worship and You we ask for help.
>
> Guide us to the straight path -
>
> The path of those upon whom You have bestowed favor, not of those who have evoked [Your] anger or of those who are astray.

And following that is the purpose of the Book:

> ذلك الكتاب لا ريب فيه هدى للمتقين
>
> This is the Book about which there is no doubt, a guidance for those conscious of Allah -
>
> <sup>— [Quran 2:1-2](https://quran.com/2/1-2?translations=20)</sup>

And this is the correct way to begin the Book.

---

**Who is the author of the Quran?**

It is repeated throughout the Book that it is the revelation and speech of Allah:

> وما كان هذا القرآن أن يفترى من دون الله
>
> And it was not [possible] for this Qur'an to be produced by other than Allah
>
> <sup>— [Quran 10:37](https://quran.com/10/37?translations=20)</sup>

> تنزيل الكتاب من الله العزيز الحكيم
>
> The revelation of the Qur'an is from Allah, the Exalted in Might, the Wise.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 39:1](https://quran.com/39/1?translations=20)</sup>

> وإنه لتنزيل رب العالمين
>
> And indeed, the Qur'an is the revelation of the Lord of the worlds.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 26:192](https://quran.com/26/192?translations=20)</sup>

> تنزيل العزيز الرحيم
>
> [This is] a revelation of the Exalted in Might, the Merciful,
>
> <sup>— [Quran 36:5](https://quran.com/36/5?translations=20)</sup>

> إنه لقرآن كريم في كتاب مكنون لا يمسه إلا المطهرون تنزيل من رب العالمين
>
> Indeed, it is a noble Qur'an. In a Register well-protected; None touch it except the purified. [It is] a revelation from the Lord of the worlds.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 56:80](https://quran.com/56/80?translations=20)</sup>

> حتى يسمع كلام الله
>
> So that he may hear the words of Allah
>
> <sup>— [Quran 9:6](https://quran.com/9/6?translations=20)</sup>

---

**Would Allah refer to himself in the third person?**

Yes He would. Referring to oneself in the third person is grammatically valid, and is common and even more eloquent.

> One of the literary styles of the Arabs is for the speaker to refer to himself in the first person and in the third person ... for Allah to speak of Himself in the third person is more eloquent
>
> <sup>— [islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/209022/)</sup>

As proof that one can refer to himself in third person, below are some examples from the Quran where Allah refers to himself in *both* the first and third person in the same verse:

> فاصبر إن وعد الله حق فإما نرينك بعض الذي نعدهم أو نتوفينك فإلينا يرجعون
>
> Indeed, the **promise of Allah** is truth. And whether We show you some of what **We have promised** them or We take you in death, it is to Us they will be returned.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 40:77](https://quran.com/40/77?translations=20)</sup>

> فمن أظلم ممن كذب بآيات الله وصدف عنها سنجزي الذين يصدفون عن آياتنا سوء العذاب بما كانوا يصدفون
>
> Then who is more unjust than one who denies the **verses of Allah** and turns away from them? We will recompense those who turn away from **Our verses** with the worst of punishment for their having turned away.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 6:157](https://quran.com/6/157?translations=20)</sup>

> أم يحسدون الناس على ما آتاهم الله من فضله فقد آتينا آل إبراهيم الكتاب والحكمة وآتيناهم ملكا عظيما
>
> Or do they envy people for what **Allah has given** them of His bounty? But **We had already given** the family of Abraham the Scripture and wisdom and conferred upon them a great kingdom.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:54](https://quran.com/4/54?translations=20)</sup>

> وما كان ربك مهلك القرى حتى يبعث في أمها رسولا يتلو عليهم آياتنا وما كنا مهلكي القرى إلا وأهلها ظالمون
>
> And never would **your Lord have destroyed** the cities until He had sent to their mother a messenger reciting to them Our verses. And **We would not destroy** the cities except while their people were wrongdoers.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 28:59](https://quran.com/28/59?translations=20)</sup>

> سندخلهم جنات تجري من تحتها الأنهار خالدين فيها أبدا وعد الله حقا ومن أصدق من الله قيلا
>
> **We will admit** them to gardens beneath which rivers flow, wherein they will abide forever. [It is] the **promise of Allah**, [which is] truth, and who is more truthful than Allah in statement.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:122](https://quran.com/4/122?translations=20)</sup>

> وأنزلنا إليك الكتاب ... فاحكم بينهم بما أنزل الله
>
> And **We have revealed** to you, [O Muhammad], the Book ... So judge between them by what **Allah has revealed** ...
>
> <sup>— [Quran 5:48](https://quran.com/5/48?translations=20)</sup>

> أفغير الله أبتغي حكما وهو الذي أنزل إليكم الكتاب مفصلا والذين آتيناهم الكتاب يعلمون أنه منزل من ربك بالحق فلا تكونن من الممترين
>
> Those to whom **We [previously] gave the Scripture** know that it is sent down **from your Lord** in truth, so never be among the doubters.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 6:114](https://quran.com/6/114?translations=20)</sup>

And there are hundreds of other such examples within the Quran.

Usage of third person to refer to oneself can also be found in ahadith, some examples are as follows where Muhammad ﷺ refers to himself in the third person:

> فقال رسول الله ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم لا كرب على أبيك بعد اليوم
>
> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said (to Fatimah his daughter): ‘**Your father** will suffer no more agony after this day.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4462) and  [Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:1629)</sup>

> عن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم أنه قال ‏ "‏ يا أمة محمد والله لو تعلمون ما أعلم لبكيتم كثيرا، ولضحكتم قليلا ‏"‏‏.‏
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "O followers of **Muhammad**! By Allah, if you knew what I know, you would weep much and laugh little."
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6631)</sup>

> يقول إن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم قال ‏ "‏ ...  من عقد لحيته أو تقلد وترا أو استنجى برجيع دابة أو عظم فإن محمدا بريء منه ‏"‏
>
> The Messenger of Allah [SAW] said: ... 'Whoever ties up his beard, or twists it, or hangs an amulet, or cleans himself with animal dung or bones, **Muhammad** has nothing to do with him.'
>
> <sup>— [Nasai](https://sunnah.com/nasai:5067)</sup>

Usage of third person for oneself can also be found in numerous pre-Islamic sources, such as in the Bible, especially when the speaker is considered to be God:

> Yahweh said to Moses ... He (Yahweh) said, “I will make all my goodness pass before you, and will proclaim **Yahweh’s name** before you. I will be gracious to whom I will be gracious, and will show mercy on whom I will show mercy.”
>
> <sup>— [Exodus 33:19](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=exodus+33&version=WEB)</sup>

> **Yahweh** descended in the cloud, and stood with him there, and proclaimed Yahweh’s name. Yahweh passed by before him, **and proclaimed, “Yahweh! Yahweh, a merciful and gracious God, slow to anger, and abundant in loving kindness and truth** ... "
>
> <sup>— [Exodus 34:6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus+34%3A6&version=WEB)</sup>

> **Yahweh**’s anger burned in that day, and **He swore, saying**: ‘Surely none of the men who came up out of Egypt, from twenty years old and upward, shall see the land which I swore to Abraham, to Isaac, and to Jacob; because they **have not wholly followed Me**, except Caleb the son of Jephunneh the Kenizzite, and Joshua the son of Nun, because **they have followed Yahweh** completely.’
>
> <sup>— [Numbers 32:10-12](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Numbers+32%3A10-12&version=WEB)</sup>

> He said, “If you will diligently listen to **Yahweh your God**’s voice, and will do that which is right in **his** eyes, and will pay attention to **his** commandments, and keep all **his** statutes, **I will** put none of the diseases on you which **I have** put on the Egyptians; for **I am Yahweh** who heals you.”
>
> <sup>— [Exodus 15:26](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus+15%3A26&version=WEB)</sup>

> But **Yahweh** said to Samuel, “Don’t look on his face, or on the height of his stature, because I have rejected him; for **I don’t see as man sees**. For man looks at the outward appearance, but **Yahweh looks at the heart**.”
>
> <sup>— [1 Samuel 16:7](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Sam+16%3A7&version=WEB)</sup>

> For **Yahweh says**, “To the eunuchs who keep **My** Sabbaths, choose the things that please **Me**, and hold fast to **My** covenant, **I** will give them in **My** house and within **My** walls a memorial and a name better than of sons and of daughters. **I** will give them an everlasting name that will not be cut off.
> Also the foreigners who join themselves to **Yahweh**  to serve **Him**, and to love **Yahweh’s name**,   to be **His** servants, everyone who keeps the Sabbath from profaning it, and holds fast **My** covenant
>
> <sup>— [Isaiah 56:4-6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah+56%3A4-6&version=WEB)</sup>

Also see [Genesis 9:5-6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+9%3A5-6&version=WEB),  [Genesis 9:14-16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+9%3A14-16&version=WEB) , [Genesis 35:1](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+35%3A1&version=WEB), [Deuteronomy 5:6-11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy+5%3A6-11&version=WEB), [Leviticus 25:36-38](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Leviticus+25%3A36-38&version=WEB) , [Exodus 3:11-12](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exod+3%3A11-12&version=WEB), [1 Chronicles 14:14-15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Chronicles+14%3A14-15&version=WEB), [Isaiah 38:5-8](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah+38%3A5-8&version=WEB),. etc.  there are hundreds of other examples within the Bible.

Comment: why is my question down-voted?

Answer (score -1):

It comes short if we understand that prophets took a dictation word-by-word. Nobody after Muhammad (p.b.u.h) has experienced to be chosen as a prophet, the last testimony is the Hadith of Muhammad (p.b.u.h). There, we can find some indication how he experienced it.

It is reported in [Bukh 1:2](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2)

> Al-Harith bin Hisham asked Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! How is the Divine Inspiration revealed to you?" Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) replied, "Sometimes it is (revealed) like the ringing of a bell, this form of Inspiration is the hardest of all and then this state passes off after I have grasped what is inspired. Sometimes the Angel comes in the form of a man and talks to me and I grasp whatever he says." 'Aisha added: Verily I saw the Prophet (ﷺ) being inspired divinely on a very cold day and noticed the sweat dropping from his forehead (as the Inspiration was over).

The prophet received it in a kind of a dialogue; there are several hadith reporting that he asked back; I found [this one:](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3219)

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "Gabriel read the Qur'an to me in one way (i.e. dialect) and I continued asking him to read it in different ways till he read it in seven different ways."

The Quran is sometimes written with God in first person (I or We) and sometimes in third person. I have tried to find out whether this has a significance but I was not successful in it, so I can't tell.

The beginning of the Quran states that Muhammad is not speaking on his own behalf but as a Messenger of God. It has finally been he who uttered the words to his companions but it is not based on his own reasoning. This is exactly what is expressed in the opening

> In the Name of Allah, the Compassionate, the Merciful."